# Read mouse coordinates click in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, math, coordinates, dev-c++

I'm trying to read the mouse coordinate when I click in a point on screen and mark It with a point, but It'isn't working.

```
     float cx = 0, cy = 0;

 glPushMatrix(); 
    glPointSize(6.0f);
    //Draw the points
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        cx = (((x * (maxx + minx))) / width) + minx;
        cy = (((-1 * pow((y - height), width) * (maxy - miny)) / height ) + miny;

        glVertex2f(cx , cy);
    glEnd();


glPopMatrix();
```

It's a college exercise, and the formula to get the coordinate from screen is:

[image: Formula to get the coordinate from screen]

Px and Py is the coordinate that mouseFunc pass to this function.
w and h is the width and height of the screen (I get It from reshape)
maxx, maxy, minx, miny... is the ortho coordinate

So, whats wrong with my code?

The mouse function (I've already tested if the mouse click is working and It is):

```
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y){
 switch(button){
       case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
            if(state == GLUT_DOWN)
                      exerciseThree(x, y);
       break;         
 }    

 glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: Could you also post the part that you get mouse coordinates?

Comment: why is the code invoking the 'pow()' system function?

Comment: @user3629249 And with a single argument, too… as written, that line should be throwing a syntax error!

Comment: @duskwuff, Sorry It was because I edited the question and forgot to open the parethesis of the pow function. It wasn't in the real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't implemented the formula you quoted correctly. Try

```
cx = x * (maxx - minx) / width + minx;
cy = (height - y) * (maxy - miny) / height + miny;
```

The two significant differences being `(maxx - minx)` in the first expression, and your misreading the second line and thinking the divisor `w` on the line above is a power for the second line.